# Сформировать массив из букв, начинающихся с заглавной буквы

Tags: c#, строки, search

На вход функции подается текст. На его основе необходимо вернуть строку, содержащие слова, в которых первая буква заглавная, в обратном порядке, встречающимся в тексте. Задача достаточно простая, но вылезает куча ошибок.

```
private static string DecodeMessage(string[] lines)
{
    string[] newArrr = lines.Split(' ');
    var newList = new List<string>();
    for(int i = 0; i < newArr.Length; i++)
        if (newArr[i][0] == newArr.ToUpper()[i][0]) newList.Add(newArr[i]);
    return newList.Reverse();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Советую все же почитать, как работать с массивами

```
    private static List<string> DecodeMessage(string[] lines)
    {
        var newList = new List<string>();
        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            string[] newArrr = line.Split(' ');


            for (int i = 0; i < newArrr.Length; i++)
            {
                var justline = newArrr[i];
                if (char.IsUpper(justline[0]))
                {
                    newList.Add(line);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return newList;
    }
```

---

Можно немного переписать

```
    private static List<string> DecodeMessage2(string[] lines)
    {
        var newList = new List<string>();
        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            var count = line.Split(' ').Where(x => char.IsUpper(x[0])).Count() ;

            if (count > 0)
                newList.Add(line);

        }
        return newList;
    }
```

---

Еще более не понятно :

```
var result = lines.Where(y=> y.Split(' ').Where(x => char.IsUpper(x[0])).Count() >0 ).ToArray();
```

Comment: Прочитал ваш ответ, понял, что я невнимательно глянул условие задачи и зря я предложил закрыть дубликатом. Отозвал свой голос за закрытие.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static string DecodeMessage(string[] lines)
{
    return string.Join(" ", string.Join(" ", lines).Split(' ').Where(str => str.Length > 0 && char.IsUpper(str[0])).Reverse());
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]